# Cannot find documentation for GRPC channel options

Tags: python, grpc

I'm looking for the documentation for the channel options I can pass when creating a gRPC channel. For example, I know there's one called `grpc.max_receive_message_length`. My problem is that I cannot find a complete list of those or a description of what they do. The only way I've found right now is to go to the source, where the options are defined in `grpc_types.h`. Is there a better way / place to get this kind of documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GRPC channel options (also called channel arguments) are defined in the `grpc_types.h` file as you noted (a current snapshot can be seen [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/618a3f561d4a93f263cca23abad086ed8f4d5e86/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h)). The github.io hosted documentation for the gRPC Core Library has the channel arguments on a single page [here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/group__grpc__arg__keys.html).

You can get there in the future by going to the gRPC website, https://grpc.io/, and go through menus for Docs > Reference > Core Library to get to the [gRPC Core Documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/index.html). From there you can navigate to the Modules page, and the only module currently listed is the [Channel arguments keys](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/group__grpc__arg__keys.html) which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete answer.

Comment: @JulienDebache No worries. I didn't know that I had this question until you asked!